# SharedPreferences value returning null after new instance

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I am setting a string in SharedPreferences through my SettingsHelper class as shown below. I had verified it has actually been set by getting the string right after its set.

A new instance of the SettingsHelper class is created.

Then i attempt to retrieve the string i set but it comes up null.

Could getName be returning null because i have created a new instance  of the SettingsHelper class?

```
public class SettingsHelper extends Application {

    private static Context context;
    Context ctx;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        ctx = context;
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return context;
    }

 public SettingsHelper() {
        this.ctx = context;
    }


 public String getName() {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).getString("myKey", "null");
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).edit().putString("myKey", name).commit();
    }
}
```

***Activity A***

```
SettingsHelper settingsHelper = new SettingsHelper();
settingsHelper.setName("John");
```

***Class B***

```
SettingsHelper settingsHelper = new SettingsHelper();
    settingsHelper.getName(); //null
```

Comment: Did you really start activity A?

Comment: Yes. I have verified that name has been set in activity A.

Answer (score 2):

Try converting the methods to static methods:

```
public class SettingsHelper {

 public static String getName(Context ctx) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).getString("myKey", "An error occured loading name");
    }

    public static void setName(String name, Context ctx) {
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx).edit().putString("myKey", name).commit();
    }
}
```

For calling(from activities). Replace this with context if it is outside activity:

```
getName(this);

setName("Namey McNameface", this);
```

That way you do not need instances, it is just to call SettingsHelper.setName/getName.

**EDIT**

Remember to asign a string:

```
SettingsHelper settingsHelper = new SettingsHelper();
String stringHandler = settingsHelper.GetName(); 
//handle string
```

**EDIT #2**

NOTE!

Extending Application is not a good idea for classes like this one. remove the 'extends application'.

> What does it matter?

Classes extending activity are for tasks that have to keep running the entire time and they are **not** initialized in the normal fasion(Class c = new Class)

Classes that extend application are initialized through the manifest by writing `android:name=".MyClass"`. These classes are used for:

- Initializing and handling Firebase
- Initializing and handling ACRA
- Initializing and handling important things like permissions(if you feel like checking them *instantly* on startup

Classes that extend application are therefore not for normal classes and I recommend that you do as I did above. Additionally, because you create it multiple times I think Context = null as well

I edited the code above, copy and try again and see if it works

Comment: Could getName be returning null because i have created a new instance though?  I was contemplating going static(last resort) or using dependency injection to solve the problem if that is the case.

Comment: i don't think its returning null cuz of new instance

Comment: It should not be in theory, but you could try the code above and see if it solves the issue

Comment: yeah you should use static for such methods

Comment: What aspect of it is null? Does it return null? If you are not asigning a string to the calling it will not be used for anything

Comment: To phrase it like this: If it is called over and over and instances are too hard to manage, go static!

Comment: It returns null. I did not add a string variable to my example to keep my code content short. I figure it helps with readability i guess not lol

Comment: Going static. Thank you

Comment: Using static methodswon't help. Issue is in other place.

Comment: Using static did not help. Still returning null. I am only accessing the setName() method once. Going to continue debugging

Comment: Do not extend application. make it a normal class

Comment: Great tip and explanation. Application removed and context referenced elsewhere

Comment: @Polarbear0106 i answered my question the root of my problem was not related. But i still made the changes you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You're extending Application class - it's wrong (or, at least - you're doing it probably in wrong way.

If you want to extend Application class you have to also declare it as Application in your manifest. Then - you shouldn't create it with new SettingsHelper() as you're creating new context each time, so probably - you're creating new preferences file each time. On other hand - onCreate() method of this class is never called, as it's not managed by system.

Better way in my opinion is to switch this helper into Object subclass, and pass context in constructor.

Comment: Going to try this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you start activity A with this code

```
SettingsHelper settingsHelper = new SettingsHelper();
settingsHelper.setName("John");
```

Then from activity A, go to activity B an call this:

```
SettingsHelper settingsHelper = new SettingsHelper();
   String stringHandler = settingsHelper.GetName();
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue turned out to unrelated. I was using "==" for code related to getting the key instead of .equals()

```
if(name == "name"){
System.out.print(true);
}
else{
System.out.print(false);
}
```

***Should be using .equals() not "==" for strings***